# how to append a view to the top of the android keyboard?

Tags: android, android-xml

I have noticed an app that I recently downloaded has their adview set up in a way that when the keyboard is inactive it will sit at the very bottom of the screen but when the keyboard pops up it sits directly on top of it I have attached 2 screen shots that hopefully will illustrate what Im trying to achieve any help would go a long way thanks!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your parent XML layout file is a RelativeLayout, you can use this on the view that holds the ad:

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```